# OR isn't functioning

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an IF statement with 3 OR, but it's not functioning.

```
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['package']);
    if ($package != 500 || $package != 1100  || $package != 2400 ) {
        $error = "Invalid Package.";
    }
```

It always echos "Invalid Package." whether $package is 500, 1100, 2400 or anything else.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Think logically...every value imaginable will match that if statement.

Comment: When is a package invalid?

Comment: `or` is working, and is doing exactly what you've asked it to do.... I think you meant to use `and`

Comment: @thumbmunkeys No, I want it if it's either 500, 1100 OR 2400.

Comment: @Voiceeeeee Take a logic course. `¬(a|b|c) = (¬a) && (¬b) && (¬c)`.

Comment: @Novocaine Hmm, can you please elaborate? I'm in a hurry right now.

Comment: If you want either 500 OR 1100 OR 2400..... then don't use `NOT`

Comment: @Naruto When $package isn't 500, 1100 or 2400.

Comment: If it is NOT 500 AND it is NOT 1100 AND it is NOT 2400

Comment: @Voiceeeeee take the value `gj5i` it != any of those conditions so it will print the error. Now take `500` it matches 2 of your conditions, but because you used an `OR` it means it only needs to match one condition. So you see any value will match at least 2 of your conditions. Which is why they need to be `AND`s

Comment: As per your edit and what worked, you should be accepting an correct answer given below; if one did work. That's not how things work on Stack. Either delete your question or accept one.

Comment: Yea, I get it everyone, I was a bit confused. Thank you all. <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

classic error :-)

you want `&&` not `||`

```
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['package']);
if ($package != 500 && $package != 1100  && $package != 2400 ) {
    $error = "Invalid Package.";
}
```

I assume your valid packages are 500, 1100 and 2400 in... hum... size???

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As per OP's edit as to what worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm just waiting for the timer to be over, haha.
32 more seconds.

Comment: @Voiceeeeee I understand. You should edit your question and remove "what worked" for you. It's not how it's done on Stack, just a quick FYI ;) *cheers.*

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a set of wrong answers, in case in the future the number 1654 also appears:

```
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['package']);
$valid_packages = array(500, 1100, 2400);
if (!in_array($package, $valid_packages)) {
    $error = "Invalid Package.";
}
```

That way if the `$package` is not 500, 1100, 2400 it's invalid.

Having it as an array allows for easy modifications later on (more/fewer packages) and much easier to hook up to an external database.

Comment: +1 for Best answer. The list could also be retrieved from an external file or a database if using this sort of method.

Comment: @Nate You may just upvote instead of doing `+1` :) either way - thanks!

Comment: The array should be called something like "*valid* _packages" in this case, not "*wrong* _packages" (and you are missing one `)` in the condition).

Answer (score 0):

if you want one of them to be true remove not (!):

```
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['package']);
    if ($package == 500 || $package == 1100  || $package == 2400 ) {
        $error = "Invalid Package.";
    }
```

Comment: You mean `$package == ...`, not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for one of them to be true here is the code

```
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['package']);
if ($package == 500 || $package == 1100  || $package == 2400 ) {
$error = "It has one of them.";
}
```